# Subquery returns more than 1 row when subselecting in a CASE WHEN statement

Tags: mysql, sql

**First query**

This query works fine and the engine does not complain about it

```
SELECT id 
FROM agencies
WHERE id IN ((SELECT id FROM agencies))
ORDER BY id;
```

**Second query**

This one does not work, the engine is complaining about `Subquery returns more than 1 row`, when -according to me- I am doing the exact same thing when `@param_1 IS NULL`

```
SELECT 
  @param_1 := NULL,

SELECT id 
FROM agencies
WHERE id IN (CASE WHEN @param_1 IS NULL THEN (SELECT id FROM agencies) ELSE 1 END )
ORDER BY id;
```

Does anybody see why the engine is complaining about the second query when it isnt for the first query ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CASE expects a scalar, single value. Not a record set.

```
SELECT id 
FROM agencies
WHERE id IN (
        SELECT id FROM agencies WHERE @param_1 IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 WHERE @param_1 IS NOT NULL
        )
ORDER BY id;
```

OR

```
SELECT id 
FROM agencies
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM agencies)
     AND @param_1 IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT id 
FROM agencies
WHERE @param_1 IS NOT NULL AND id = 1
ORDER BY id;
```

Another choice is to use IF

```
IF @param_1 IS NULL
    SELECT id 
    FROM agencies
    WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM agencies)
    ORDER BY id;
ELSE
    SELECT id 
    FROM agencies
    WHERE id = 1
    ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: Ahh beat me by 11 seconds! At least I'm chuffed we've got the same answer lol.

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
SELECT id 
FROM agencies
WHERE id IN (
                SELECT id
                FROM agencies
                WHERE @param_1 IS NULL

                UNION ALL

                SELECT 1 as id
                WHERE @param_1 IS NOT NULL
)
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: UNION ALL will better because it is a binary choice. It may not matter to the optimiser of course, but it won't hurt